# Receive DeviceMotion updates while phone in background

Tags: ios, background, navigation, core-motion

I have a navigation app that uses core motion to receive CMDeviceMotion updates. How can I continue to receive and process these updates if the phone has been put to sleep or is running in the background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this automatically works by virtue of having the location update background mode turned on.